# WMTS Error when adding Mapbox Layer to QGIS: Failed to download capabilities?

Tags: qgis, tiles, mapbox, wmts, mapbox-studio

I've tried this a few different ways and can't quite get it to work using QGIS's add WMTS layer tool. The URL loads fine in a browser but won't download as a tile in QGIS. I don't have that good an understanding of how this works/ permissions stuff either - I'm not even sure what it means by capabilities. Any advice?

Full error text:

```
Failed to download capabilities:
Download of capabilities failed: Error transferring (URL)
-server replied: Not Found
```

Mapbox URL:[https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/cdickinson11/cjkwiea7n0raq2rp9gvab9hc4/tiles/256/{level}/{col}/{row}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2RpY2tpbnNvbjExIiwiYSI6ImNqY3J6eDlscTBweHMycXMwcWltbnRiN3MifQ.X68p3M-5wwH3AudbxEYdfw](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/cdickinson11/cjkwiea7n0raq2rp9gvab9hc4/tiles/256/%7Blevel%7D/%7Bcol%7D/%7Brow%7D@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2RpY2tpbnNvbjExIiwiYSI6ImNqY3J6eDlscTBweHMycXMwcWltbnRiN3MifQ.X68p3M-5wwH3AudbxEYdfw)

EDIT: Went back and tried to create a link using [this](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mapbox-arcgis-qgis/#finished-product) guide from mapbox. Still no luck. New error: not a wms server.

New, homemade link:

https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/cdickinson11/cjkwiea7n0raq2rp9gvab9hc4.html?fresh=true&title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2RpY2tpbnNvbjExIiwiYSI6ImNqY3J6eDlscTBweHMycXMwcWltbnRiN3MifQ.X68p3M-5wwH3AudbxEYdfw#0.8/-0.000000/0.000000/0/wmts?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2RpY2tpbnNvbjExIiwiYSI6ImNqZThwZGg1dDAyMngzM3Fsdmp0dm82YTcifQ.bjVqusaDZqdZVWunQ0xS7A[4](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/cdickinson11/https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/cdickinson11/cjkwiea7n0raq2rp9gvab9hc4.html?fresh=true&title=true&access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiY2RpY2tpbnNvbjExIiwiYSI6ImNqY3J6eDlscTBweHMycXMwcWltbnRiN3MifQ.X68p3M-5wwH3AudbxEYdfw#0.8/-0.000000/0.000000/0/wmts?access_token=%3Cpk.eyJ1IjoiY2RpY2tpbnNvbjExIiwiYSI6ImNqZThwZGg1dDAyMngzM3Fsdmp0dm82YTcifQ.bjVqusaDZqdZVWunQ0xS7A%3E)

Comment: please provide the url for us to test

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WMTS endpoint documented at https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-a-maps-wmts-document

Comment: So, I tried that and this is the message I got back. I'm not too familiar with curl, so perhaps I did something wrong?                                                                                  [1] 26799
[2] 26800
[2]+  Done                    title=true
Coreys-MacBook-Pro:~ coreydickinson$ {"message":"Not Authorized - No Token"}
[1]+  Done                    curl

Comment: Fixed it! Realized I was not typing in things in the right place. Just for reference purposes, could you explain how I could have used curl to solve my problem?

Comment: Sounds like you didn't put the URL in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Better off using XYZ instead of WMTS from mapbox